# What is the difference between chirality and chiral symmetry?

Tags: terminology, definition, symmetry

The Wikipedia article of [Chiral symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_symmetry) doesn't differentiate the two terms "chiral symmetry" and "chirality", hence confusing me. Are they the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, chiral comes from the Greek word χέρι for hand. But in a way chirality and chiral symmetry are opposites: Both your hands *together* are an object with **chiral symmetry** because "mirror image of two hands" looks the same as "two hands" - though the reflection interchanges the hands, so to speak. On the other, erm, hand, a single hand (your right hand, say) shows the property of **chirality** because its mirror image looks different (like a left hand).

Comment: So the chiral symmetry object contains two objects, each of them is chirality? Are those two objects necessary apart? Also, what is the different between "chiral symmetry" and "reflection symmetry"?